# Sorting unspecified amount of numbers in Lua

Tags: sorting, lua

I need to sort and unspecifed amount of numbers in Lua. For example if  I have theese numbers 15,21,31,50,32,11,11. I need to lua to sort them so the first one is the biggest like this: 50,32,31,21,15,11,11.

What is the easiest way to do this? Remember it got to work with an unspecified amont of numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`table.sort` sorts a table in place. By default, it uses `<` to compare elements. To sort them  with the bigger element before smaller element:

```
local t = {15, 21, 31, 50, 32, 11, 11}
table.sort(t, function(a, b) return a > b end)
```

The number of elements doesn't matter, as a table can hold as many elements as possible.